# Identifying two consecutive character in a long string is Alphanumeric (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL,is there any way to find a alphanumeric string in a long string and if alphanumeric string found I want to make the alphabet character to be capital.

Eg:

1. "DSP FTP  Series 33 - 24m - Reg - G"
2. "DSP FMP - Series 166 - 3m - Reg - G"

From the 1st example mentioned above I want to make 'm' of '24m' to be capital 'M' and in 2nd example I want to make 'm' of '3m' to be capital 'M'.Is there a way to do this within SQL.

Comment: What's the rules? How do you identify what letter you want to make capital?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a pure guess...

```
SELECT ISNULL(STUFF(YourColumn,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9]m %',@str),0)+1,1,'M'),YourColumn);
```

This *assumes* that there will always be a white space after the `'m'` (and it's always an M you want to make a capital).

If this isn't the case, provide more comprehensive sample data that shows a range of scenarios we need to work with.

A more comprehensive answer, that handles varying letters (still needs a space afterwards though).

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT 'DSP FTP Series 33 - 24m - Reg - G' AS YourColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DSP FMP - Series 166 - 3m - Reg - G'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DSP FQP - Series 1000 - 4d - Reg - G'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ASP WEP - Series B - Regular'
)
SELECT V.YourColumn,
       ISNULL(STUFF(V.YourColumn,PI.I+1,1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(V.YourColumn,PI.I+1,1))),V.YourColumn) AS NewColumn
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][a-z] %',V.YourColumn),0))) PI(I);
```

Comment: Why bother guessing? If the question is missing critical details, why not ask before posting an answer (that has a good chance of being wrong)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Larnu. Not necessary every time it will me 'M' it can be any alphabet. Scenarios are as follows "DSP FMP  Series 127 - 3c - Reg - G"
"FILife SF Of Funds - 20s Plan - Direct  Dividend Payout"
"DSP FMP - Series 167 - 12m - Reg - G"

Comment: @Prasad hence why, as Zohar Peled mentioned, why you need to make your question more comprehensive. However, I have just updated the answer to cater for that,